Issue with Nested Tabs and Page Scrolling in Flutter
Design
We've implemented a nested tabs design in our Flutter app, comprising two main tabs: "Expense" and "Income." Within each tab, we display a bar chart illustrating monthly expenses for the past 12 months. Additionally, each tab has two child tabs: "Latest" and "Crop-wise Expense." The "Latest" tab exhibits a ListView of expense records, while the "Crop-wise" tab showcases a pie chart followed by a list of crops. Please refer to the attached design for visuals. (The design is finalized and operational.)
Expectation:
Our expectation is to achieve a page scrolling behavior akin to Facebook or Instagram feeds, enabling users to vertically scroll the entire page, including the bar chart and pie chart. It would be preferable if the scrolling extends beyond the app bar when navigating through the data.
Actual:
Currently, the bar chart remains static, and the only scrolling functionality is observed within the child tabs, specifically in the latest records and crop-wise records. Even within these child tabs, once the pie chart is scrolled, it fails to return to its original position.
Questions:
Can someone please provide insights into whether there are any design flaws causing this issue? We've been unable to find examples of nested tabs with similar behavior.
We suspect the presence of the bar chart between the parent and child tabs might be contributing to the problem. How can we implement scrolling within this design? Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Code implementation as below,
Income & Expense Screen :
class NewDashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List<ExpenseModel>> expenses;

  NewDashBoard({required this.expenses});

  @override
  _NewDashBoardState createState() => _NewDashBoardState();
}

class _NewDashBoardState extends State<NewDashBoard> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late TabController _tabController1;
  List<ViewExpenseModel> latestExpenses = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  int? _sliding = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchLatestExpenses();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _tabController1 = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    _tabController1.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchLatestExpenses() async {
    try {
      List<ViewExpenseModel> expenses = await DbHelper().getLatestExpenses();
      setState(() {
        latestExpenses = expenses;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting latest expenses: $e');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers:<Widget> [
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    Container(
                     // constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: ResponsiveUtil.screenHeight(context) * 0.10,
                            width: ResponsiveUtil.screenHeight(context),
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 38.0, left: 8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: ColorConstants.miniIconDefaultColor),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        PageTransition(
                                          child: HomeScreen(),
                                          type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "Income & Expense Analysis",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: SizeConstants.appBarTitleFontSIze,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: TabBar(
                              controller: _tabController,
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                              labelColor: Colors.white,
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(child: Text("Expenses", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: SizeConstants.appBarTabViewTitleFontSIze))),
                                Tab(child: Text("Income", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: SizeConstants.appBarTabViewTitleFontSIze))),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: ResponsiveUtil.screenHeight(context) * 0.20,
                            child: MyBarChart(),
                          ),
                          DefaultTabController(
                            length: 2,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: TabBar(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    controller: _tabController1,
                                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                                    labelColor: Colors.green,
                                    tabs: [
                                      Tab(child: Text("Latest", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16))),
                                      Tab(child: Text("CropWise", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16))),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55, // Adjust the height as needed
                                  child: TabBarView(
                                    controller: _tabController1,
                                    children: [
                                      DashboardScreen(),
                                      MyPieChartWidget(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                  ]
                )
            )

          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Barchart :

class MyBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBarChart();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarChart(
      BarChartData(
        barTouchData: barTouchData,
        titlesData: titlesData,
        borderData: borderData,
        barGroups: barGroups,
        gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
        alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceAround,
        maxY: 20,
      ),
    );
  }

  BarTouchData get barTouchData => BarTouchData(
    enabled: false,
    touchTooltipData: BarTouchTooltipData(
      //getTooltipColor: (group) => Colors.transparent,
      tooltipPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      tooltipMargin: 8,
      getTooltipItem: (
          BarChartGroupData group,
          int groupIndex,
          BarChartRodData rod,
          int rodIndex,
          ) {
        return BarTooltipItem(
          rod.toY.toString(),
          const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  Widget getTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    final style = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      fontSize: 14,
    );
    String text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 0:
        text = 'Jan';
        break;
      
      case 11:
        text = 'Dec';
        break;
      default:
        text = '';
        break;
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 4,
      child: Text(text, style: style),
    );
  }

  FlTitlesData get titlesData => FlTitlesData(
    show: true,
    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
      sideTitles: SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        reservedSize: 30,
        getTitlesWidget: getTitles,
      ),
    ),
    leftTitles: const AxisTitles(
      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
    ),
    topTitles: const AxisTitles(
      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
    ),
    rightTitles: const AxisTitles(
      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
    ),
  );

  FlBorderData get borderData => FlBorderData(
    show: false,
  );

  LinearGradient get _barsGradient => const LinearGradient(
    colors: [
     ColorConstants.barchartBarColor,
      ColorConstants.barchartBarColor,
    ],
    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    end: Alignment.topCenter,
  );

  List<BarChartGroupData> get barGroups => [
    BarChartGroupData(
      x: 0,
      barRods: [
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: 11,
            color: ColorConstants.barchartBarColor,
        //  gradient: _barsGradient,
        )
      ],
     // showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
    ),
    BarChartGroupData(
      x: 1,
      barRods: [
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: 10,
            color: ColorConstants.barchartBarColor,
          //gradient: _barsGradient,
        )
      ],
    //  showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
    ),
   
    BarChartGroupData(
      x: 11,
      barRods: [
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: 16,
            color: ColorConstants.barchartBarColor,
         // gradient: _barsGradient,
        )
      ],
     // showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
    ),

  ];
}

class BarChartSample3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const BarChartSample3({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => BarChartSample3State();
}

class BarChartSample3State extends State<BarChartSample3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.6,
      child: MyBarChart(),
    );
  }
}

Latest Expense :

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: DashboardScreen(),
  ));
}

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardScreenState createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
 
  List<ViewExpenseModel> latestExpenses = [];
  bool showAll = false;
  bool isLoading = true;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchLatestExpenses();
  }

  Future<void> fetchLatestExpenses() async {
    try {
      List<ViewExpenseModel> expenses = await DbHelper().getLatestExpenses();
      setState(() {
        latestExpenses = expenses;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting latest expenses: $e');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       /* appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dashboard'),
          centerTitle: false,
        ),*/
        body: isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                   
              SingleChildScrollView(

                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: ListView.builder(

                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: showAll
                      ? latestExpenses.length
                      : latestExpenses.length > 5
                      ? 5
                      : latestExpenses.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index < latestExpenses.length) {
                      return Card(
                        surfaceTintColor: ColorConstants.listViewSurfaceTintColor,
                        elevation: 1.5,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: ListTile(
                          tileColor: Colors.white,
                          title: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: '${latestExpenses[index].cropName}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: SizeConstants.listViewTitleFontSize,
                                        fontWeight: SizeConstants.listViewDataFontSemiBold,
                                        color: Colors.black, // Adjust as needed
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text:' ,${latestExpenses[index].farmName}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: SizeConstants.listViewData15FontSize,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        color: Colors.black, // Adjust as needed
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '${latestExpenses[index].expenseType}',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '${latestExpenses[index].expenseDate.day}.${latestExpenses[index].expenseDate.month}.${latestExpenses[index].expenseDate.year}',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                            '\₹${latestExpenses[index].amount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: SizeConstants.listViewData16FontSize,
                              fontWeight: SizeConstants.listViewDataFontSemiBold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'No more records !',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: SizeConstants.listViewData16FontSize,
                            fontWeight: SizeConstants.listViewDataFontSemiBold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              if (latestExpenses.length > 5)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      if (!showAll)
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              showAll = true;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text('Show All'),
                        ),
                      if (showAll)
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              showAll = false;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text('Hide'),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
      
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 
}





Cropwise :
Future<List<ExpensePieChartModel>> getExpenseForPieChartByCrop() async {
  List<ExpensePieChartModel> expenses =
  await DbHelper().getExpenseForPieChartByCrop();
  return expenses ?? [];
}

class MyPieChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPieChartWidgetState createState() => _MyPieChartWidgetState();
}

class _MyPieChartWidgetState extends State<MyPieChartWidget> {
  DbHelper? dbHelper;
  List<ExpensePieChartModel> _expenses = [];
  List<ViewExpenseModel> _latestExpenses = [];
  int touchedIndex = -1;

  // Index to keep track of the current color
  int colorIndex = 0;

  // Convert the hexadecimal colors to Color objects
  List<Color> pieChartColors = ColorConstants.pieChartHexColors
      .map((hexColor) =>
      Color(int.parse(hexColor.substring(1), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000))
      .toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DbHelper();
    _fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    List<ExpensePieChartModel> expenses = await getExpenseForPieChartByCrop();
    List<ViewExpenseModel> latestExpenses =
    await DbHelper().getLatestExpenses();
    setState(() {
      _expenses = expenses;
      _latestExpenses = latestExpenses;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: ResponsiveUtil.screenHeight(context),
            width: ResponsiveUtil.screenWidth(context),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                if (_expenses.isEmpty)
                  _expenses == null
                      ? Center(child: Text('No records to show'))
                      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                else
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: ResponsiveUtil.screenHeight(context) * 0.42,
                          // width: ResponsiveUtil.screenWidth(context) * 0.1,
                          child: PieChart(
                            PieChartData(
                              sections: _expenses.map((expense) {
                                // Get the color from the list based on the current index
                                Color selectedColor =
                                pieChartColors[colorIndex];

                                // Increment the index for the next section
                                colorIndex =
                                    (colorIndex + 1) % pieChartColors.length;

                                return PieChartSectionData(
                                  radius: 99.0,
                                  title: expense.cropName,
                                  value: expense.totalAmountSpent.toDouble(),
                                  color: selectedColor,
                                  titleStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
                              sectionsSpace: 5.0,
                              centerSpaceRadius: 20,
                              //sections: showingSections(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: ResponsiveUtil.screenHeight(context) * 0.55,
                          child: FutureBuilder<List<CropModel>>(
                            future: dbHelper!.getAllCrops(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                );
                              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                                );
                              } else if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                                  snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text(LocaleKeys
                                      .labelMessageNoCropAvailable
                                      .tr()),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    CropModel crop = snapshot.data![index];
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                CropWiseExpenses(
                                                  cropId: crop.cropId ?? 0,
                                                  cropName: crop.cropName,
                                                ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: Card(
                                        surfaceTintColor: ColorConstants
                                            .listViewSurfaceTintColor,
                                        elevation: 1.5,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            12.0, 5.0, 12.0, 5.0),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                .spaceBetween,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Column(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment
                                                      .start,
                                                  children: [
                                                    SizedBox(height: 18.0),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          crop.cropName ?? '',
                                                          style:
                                                          const TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                            SizeConstants
                                                                .listViewDataFontSemiBold,
                                                            fontSize:
                                                            SizeConstants
                                                                .listViewData16FontSize,
                                                            color: ColorConstants
                                                                .listViewTitleTextColor,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                        // data limit reached, code removed
                                                       


Have you tried using auto_route package? It seems like it will be perfect for your needs as you can split those section into its own screen and use AutoRouter() to render them into your parent screen. This way, you can achieve scrolling in both the parent and the child and they are both independent of each other. It's just a suggestion, I have never tried it myself.
